# Why JSON.parse('[123]') returns 123?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I don't understand why `JSON.parse('[123]')` returns an integer `123`? Shouldn't it return an array `[123]`?

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2z355/3/).

How can I get an array of a single integer after `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: `Array.isArray(JSON.parse('[123]')) === true`.

Comment: `>> JSON.parse('[123]') // [123]` - what r u talkin bout ? and it is ==123 and not ===123. js just tries to extract numbers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It *is* an array, only when it is printed, the brackets are not printed.

Take a look at this one with two items: http://jsfiddle.net/2z355/4/

It prints as `123,456`, also without brackets.

```
el.innerHTML = JSON.parse('[123]');  // The one item: 123
el.innerHTML = JSON.parse('[123]')[0]; // First item of array: 123
el.innerHTML = JSON.parse('[123,456]') // Both values: 123,456;
el.innerHTML = JSON.parse('[123,456]')[0] // First item: 123;
```

And also

```
el.innerHTML = typeof JSON.parse('123'); // number
el.innerHTML = typeof JSON.parse('[123]'); // object *)
```

I'd have expected 'array' there, but it turns out to be an object. Maybe I've been PHPing too much lately. Nevertheless, it's not a number. :)
Fortunately the next line *will* work (thanks to icktoofay).

```
el.innerHTML = JSON.parse('[123]') instanceof Array; // true
```

Comment: An additional example: JSON.parse("[1,[[2],3]]") = 1,2,3

Comment: Damn, I should have just checked its type. By the way, in JavaScript there is no "array" data type that's why it's displaying "object". `Array` is just a descendant of `Object`.

Answer (score 6):

It is an array of a single integer; it's just that a quirk of JavaScript makes the string representation of an array be the string representations of the elements joined by commas, *without the `[` and `]`*.

You know it's an array because

1. `result instanceof Array`
2. `JSON.stringify(result) === '[123]'`